# Is it a bad practice to use a BlockingObservable in this context?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a use case where I'm calling four separate downstream endpoints and they can all be called in parallel.  After every call is completed, I return a container object from the lambda function, its only purpose being to contain the raw responses from the downstream calls on it. From there, the container object will be transformed into the required model for the consumer.

Here's the structure of the code, roughly speaking:

```
Observable.zip(o1, o2, o3, o4, 
(resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4) 
-> new RawResponseContainer(resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4)
).toBlocking().first();
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I 100% need every observable to complete; otherwise, the transformation of the consumer model will be incomplete.  While I suppose I could transform each individual response from each observable "on the fly", rather than waiting to transform every response at once, I still need every call to finish before the transformation's done.

I've read it's a bad practice to ever use toBlocking() when using rx (aside from for 'legacy' apps), so any help's appreciated.

Comment: Look I don't know the answer to your question as I am not a Java developer, however you may consider to post this question Also to (Code Review)[https://codereview.stackexchange.com/#]  As is excatly for question for best practices.

Comment: Refer the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a response, a comment:

You are asking, essentially a sequential vs. parallel processing question. What you are doing is sequential processing (by blocking), what is recommended is parallel. Though which is better over the other is complete on the context. In your case, you need all the responses, even in parallel model all has to complete successfully. If even one fails, the entire processing is for naught. In parallel, every processing will occur if one fails all 3 would go to waste. In sequential, it would generate error in the middle. If you can live with the latency sequential processing brings, stay with it. Sequential processing are (in general) are less complicated implementations.

Comment: Gotcha.  I seemed to have been misusing 'parallel' all this time, which to me just means "http calls happening at the same time, and they're not dependent on each other to return a result".  By contrast, my understanding is 'synchronous' calls are calls you make in sequential steps.  call2 needs data from call1, call3 needs data from call2, and so on.

Back to the context of the question, I do need data from all 4 of the calls; otherwise my consumer wouldn't be able to make sense of the data being returned to them (it'd just be incomplete).